# Jquery required field error

Tags: jquery

I have added a required field validator to a textbox thorugh Jquery, but the problem is that. The message is coming continously whenever I remove the cursor from the textbox without filling any data. Please help me with this.
Please find the code for your reference:

```
var NRI_ReferFriend = function () {
var that = {};

var focusset = false;

var getError = function (str) {
    return '<span class="error_msg">' + str + '</span>';
};

var SetFocus = function (element) {
    if (!focusset) {
        $(element).focus();
        focusset = true;
    }
};

var IsEmpty = function (id) {
    var element = $('#' + id);

    $(element).parent().find('.error_msg').remove();

    if (element.val() == '' || element.val() == undefined) {
        $(element).parent().append(getError("Required.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;       "));
        SetFocus(element);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Also see the code for variable ValidateMobileNo :-

```
var ValidateMobileNo = function (id) {
    var reg = /^\d{10,11}$/;

    var element = $('#' + id);


    if (element.val() == '') {
        $(element).parent().append(getError("Required"));
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $(element).parent().find('.error_msg').remove();
    }

    $(element).parent().find('.error_msg').remove();

    if (reg.test(element.val())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $(element).parent().append(getError("Invalid Mobile No."));
        SetFocus(element);
        return false;
    }
};
```

The message "Required" is coming continously, I tried adjusting code, but couldn't find the exact solution fot it. Please help

Comment: How and where are you calling `IsEmpty` ?

Comment: You should provide your HTML as well. And maybe even full example in fiddle.

Comment: @Spokey: i am calling IsEmpty on an aspx page.

Comment: @Regent: Please see the Js fiddle for your reference:-http://jsfiddle.net/xnj2p6jq/

Comment: is anyone there to help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call the IsEmpty() method for the required textbox.